# ContextMenuService in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, contextmenu

what is the namespace of `ContextMenuService` in Silverlight 4?

I want to use ContextMenu control in Silverlight 4. but I dont know which namespace should I add in the xaml in order to use ContextMenu control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ContextMenuService` is the `System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit` namespace.  So you'll need to install the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) and reference the System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll.

Comment: Oh! thank you Sir. downloading the toolkit now. let me check it after installation.